# qliksense not getting longer strings from hive

Tags: qliksense

We have a few dashboards, wherein we source data from Apache Hive (CDH). the data is sourced through Cloudera hive ODBC connection.

What we are observing is that longer string values from source (e.g. longer than 275-280 chars) show up as null in qliksense.

wondering if anyone else has faced similar issues ? how was it handled then ?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

The Cloudera Hive Driver sets the default length of strings to 255. This is due to limitations on hive and its metadata. From the driver guide -

> In the Default String Column Length field, type the default string
>   column length to use. Note: Hive does not provide the length for
>   String columns in its column metadata. This option allows you to tune
>   the length of String columns.

In the driver configuration, go to Advanced settings, and you can edit the default length for string columns. When i set the length to 99999, all my relevant attributes flowed through.

Hope it helps others.